# Run case assignment rules after approvals

Tags: approval-process, assignment-rules

I am building a complex case management platform for an airline client for whom all cases must be approved BEFORE they are assigned to queues.

We note that because of sequencing within SFDC that the field update in the final approval actions (approval status=Approved) is not detected and needs a further EDIT & SAVE to happen on the case to cause the assignment rules to fire and correctly assign the case to the required queue.

In summary - ideas sought on how to get the assignment rules to fire at the end of or as consequence of an approval process field update (will consider apex if needed).

Comment: Can you post the picture of workflow field update configuration screen in this question

Comment: Hi @Michael Cunningham, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit [help], scroll through [tour], and read [ask]. There is no need to mention help or thanks in your posts. include screenshots, code (when applicable) so others can better assist you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a checkbox field like `isApproved` and during final approval action update this field from workflow field update.

Since you are using `Assign using active assignment rules` checkbox to fire assignment, which cannot be automatically possible after workflow field update as you are not in UI.

So, you need to write an after update trigger to fire assignment rule:

```
trigger CaseAssignment on Case (after update) {
    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        for (Case caseObj : Trigger.new)
        {
            Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(caseObj.id);
            if (!oldCase.isApproved__c && caseObj.isApproved__c) {
                caseList.add(new Case(id = caseObj.id));
            }
        }
    }
    Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
    Database.update(caseList, dmo);
}
```

Refer [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

> If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time), in addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run again.

---

> Approval Process setup:

If Type is Electronic it will be submitted for approval and after getting approved, `isApproved` field will be updated to `true`.

[image: approval]

> Case assignment rule:

[image: assignment rule]

> Case record during submission for approval

[image: during submission]

> Case is assigned to queue after getting approved, by virtue of after trigger to fire assignment rule.

[image: case after approval]

Comment: Thanks SanatanuTry this -  I think you will be surprised (as I am) at the outcome.

Comment: Sorry unsure how to upload pics here but be assured the field update is already set to reevalute workflow rules - that is not the issue. I have read on forums that this IS normal and down to that fact that Assignment rules run BEFORE field updates (if not so - please advise) – Michael Cunningham 8 mins ago    
     
Due to validation that must take place before Approval we are using a custom button to call the Approval process. Would it be possible to cause an event AFTER the approval that could cause the assignment rules to fire? any thoughts? – Michael Cunningham

Comment: Yes, that is possible, assignment rule fires after "after trigger" so, you need to update the field value so that after trigger will fire followed by assignment rule

Comment: I have updated my answer and I have checked it is working fine and assign to queue through assignment rule which is initiated through after update trigger. If this solves your purpose then accept the answer, so that others may find this useful. If you need any further help, I could able to post all the screenshots by which I have solved the problem. thanks

Comment: Santanu - this is awesome and exactly what I think Im after.  Wont be able to try it out tonight  but itching to give this a go.   Will report back on outcome asap.   thanks again Michael

Comment: Gave this after-update trigger a go in my developer org and its working a treat!!.  Great work Santanu - cant thank you enough for this ingenious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this feature in approval process ?
[image]

Comment: Sorry unsure how to upload pics here but be assured the field update is already set to reevalute workflow rules - that is not the issue.
I have read on forums that this IS normal and down to that fact that Assignment rules run BEFORE field updates (if not so - please advise)

Comment: Due to validation that must take place before Approval we are using a custom button to call the Approval process.  Would it be possible to cause an event AFTER the approval that could cause the assignment rules to fire?   any thoughts?

Comment: As @ Santanu Boral write. Create "after trigger".